# Transform a dynamic alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, bash

I have a Build called `700-I20190808-0201`. I need to convert it to `7.0.0-I20190808-0201`. I can do that with regular expression:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\(.\)/\1.\2.\3\4/' abc.txt
```

But the solution does not work when the build ID is 7001-I20190809-0201. Can we make the regular expression dynamic so that it works for both (700 and 7001)?

Comment: What should your regex output for `7001-I20190809-0201`?

Comment: 7.0.0.1-I20190808-0201

Comment: With Perl, it is really easy, `perl -i -pe 's/\G\d(?=\d)/$&./g' abc.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{gsub(/[0-9]/,"&.",$1);sub(/\.$/,"",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Perl available, lookahead regular expressions make this straightforward:

```
$ cat foo.txt
700-I20190808-0201
7001-I20190809-0201
$ perl -ple 's/(\d)(?=\d+\-I)/\1./g' foo.txt
7.0.0-I20190808-0201
7.0.0.1-I20190809-0201
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple loop using labels and branching using sed:

```
$ echo '7001-I20190809-0201' | sed ':1; s/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\([0-9][-.]\)/\1.\2/; t1'
7.0.0.1-I20190809-0201
$ echo '700-I20190809-0201' | sed ':1; s/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\([0-9][-.]\)/\1.\2/; t1'
7.0.0-I20190809-0201
```

If your sed support `-E` flag:

```
sed -E ':1; s/^([0-9]+)([0-9][-.])/\1.\2/; t1'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\(.\)/\1.\2.\3.\4/' -e 's/\.\-/\-/' abc.txt
```

This worked for me, very simple one. Just needed to extract it in my ant script using replaceregex pattern