# sed: replace characters before '-'

Tags: sed

I have a text file like so:

```
every-    100
atmo-   220
```

I wish to replace character before `-` with `*`. So the expected output should be

```
*****-    100
****-   220
```

How would I do that using sed?
I have tried using `s/[a-z]*-/*/g` but it does not work and replaces before and including the `-` with a single `*`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Implement a loop using labels and branching:

```
$ sed ':1; s/^\(\**\)[a-z]/\1*/; t1' <<EOF
every-    100
atmo-   220
EOF
*****-    100
****-   220
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/.(?=.*-)/*/g' file
```

Output:

```
*****-    100
****-   220
```

---

Derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458869/3776858

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk. Use `-` as input and output field separator and replace in first column everything with `*`.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} gsub(/./,"*",$1)' file
```

Output:

```
*****-    100
****-   220
```

Comment: IMHO this is not checking about substituting only alphabets, it will substitute anything either integer or character before `-` too.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind I have taken inspiration from your this solution and added 1 in mine with slight changes please.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of coding it in `sed`:

```
$ sed ':loop ; /[^*]-/s/[^*]/*/ ; t loop' <<END
every-    100
atmo-   220
END
*****-    100
****-   220
```

And an alternative coding in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/[^*]/*/ while /[^*]-/'
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/-/\n/;h;s/[^\n]/*/g;G;s/\n.*\n/-/' file
```

This uses a newline as a delimiter and a copy to achieve the required result

- Replace the `-` by a newline.
- Copy the line.
- Replace everything except the newline by `*`'s.
- Append the copy.
- Replace everything between the newlines by a single `-`.

An alternative, using a loop:

```
sed ':a;s/^\(\**\)[^-*]/\1*/;ta' file
```